# Why "≠" is converted to "â‰ ", "≥" to "â‰¥", "≤" to "â‰¤" in browsers developers tool(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on Javascript/angularjs. From UI, i get symbols as below:

```
'>' Greater Than
'<' Less Than
'=' Equal
'≠' Not Equal
'≥' Greater Than or Equal to
'≤' Less Than or Equal to
```

I am using switch case on received symbol

```
switch (operand) {
   case '>':
       value = blabla1; break;
   case '<':
       value = blabla2; break;
   case '=':
       value = blabla3; break;
   case '≠':
       value = blabla4; break;
    case '≥':
       value = blabla5; break;
    case '≤':
       value = blabla6; break;
   default:
       value = xyz;
      }
```

My issue is the above gets converted to below in browser`("≠" is converted to "â‰ ", "≥" to "â‰¥", "≤" to "â‰¤" )`. From which I am not able to do calculations.

```
switch (operand) {
   case '>':
       value = blabla1; break;
   case '<':
       value = blabla2; break;
   case '=':
       value = blabla3; break;
   case 'â‰ ':
       value = blabla4; break;
    case 'â‰¥':
       value = blabla5; break;
    case 'â‰¤':
       value = blabla6; break;
   default:
       value = xyz;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why this is happening? I have used charset="utf-8" in html. Also i tried in online to change the above symbols to encode and decode but none of them resulted in the exact symbol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that operand come from a text field by any chance? Seems it's gettings encoded.

Comment: Looks like your characters is encoded in other than `urf-8`. Does not look like HTML entities encoding.

Comment: @Shilly operand gets proper symbol(not encode/decode).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your browser is also using UTF-8 encoding.

[Here](https://support.google.com/news/answer/61689?hl=en)'s a link that will help you check and change your browser's encoding.

Comment: This issue is there in all browsers. I have verified it is utf-8 in browsers tool. Also I used online decoders to see if it is same value after encoding but the value is different.

Comment: Is it not working even after you change the encoding?

Comment: What editor are you writing the code in? Is your editor set to UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. It is set to UTF-8

Comment: I just did change of different encoding in browser tools then I came back to UTF-8 encoding. Now my symbols are loading.
Now how can I ask a client to do the same?
Can u suggest a way so that the browser reloads UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Check your IntelliJ encoding at the file level, project level. Also could you provide me with a running code of some sort so that i can recreate the problem on my system. :)

Edit: Working now. Great!

Comment: I think it should work at the client side without any problems. You should still test it out though.

Comment: It is reported from client. I cleared cache and then I am back to the same issue. Now, whatever I am changing in browser tools, it is not changing the symbols.